# What exception class to use for file parsing error?

Tags: python, exception

I'm writing a parser for a certain file format. If a file is not correctly formatted (and can not be parsed) then the parser throws an exception.

What exception class, in the Python 2 exception hierarchy, should I use?

Comment: See also the section on [user-defined exceptions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#user-defined-exceptions) in the Python tutorial.

Comment: @Sven Marnach: The parser is part of an extension module written using Boost.Python. And I have no idea how to derive new exception classes using the Python C-API or Boost.Python. Therefore I prefer to use one of the existing exception classes. Possible candidates seem to be Exception, ValueError and IOError.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261858/boostpython-export-custom-exception.  If your actual problem is how to create a custom exception class with boost.python, you have asked the wrong question. :)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620268/boost-python-custom-exception-class

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about

```
class XyzParseError(Exception):
    pass
```

where `XyzParser` is the name of your parser class?  That's also what [`HTMLParser`](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html#HTMLParser.HTMLParseError) in the standard library does.

Comment: Why should I derive from Exception instead of ValueError (as suggested by jkbr)?

Comment: @user763305: jkbr did not suggest to *derive* from `ValueError`, but to use `ValueError` itself.  You should derive from `Exception` because people writing `except ValueError` most certainly don't want to catch `XyzParseError`.

Comment: there are too many good and ready to use exception classes, no need for XyzParseError

Comment: @ups When catching exceptions, you want to be able to be as specific as possible.  Catching unwanted exceptions hides errors and leads to hard-to-debug bugs.  So if you reuse `ValueError` here and catch this instead of a custom exception, you risk catching exceptions that you did not intend to catch.

Answer (score 17):

[`ValueError`](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.ValueError) seems to be appropriate.