# boost::python export custom exception and inherit from Python's Exception

Tags: c++, exception, boost-python

The accepted answer to [boost::python Export Custom Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261858/boostpython-export-custom-exception) shows how to export a custom exception class from C++, and [Boost.Python custom exception class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620268/boost-python-custom-exception-class) shows how to export an exception class that inherits from Python's Exception. How can I do both? That is expose an exception class that has custom methods to retrieve information and also have that class be derived from Python's Exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A workable solution, suggested by Jim Bosch on the [C++-sig list](http://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/cplusplus-sig), is to use composition instead of inheriting from the wrapped C++ exception. The code must create a Python exception as is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620268/boost-python-custom-exception-class), and then add the wrapped C++ exception as an instance variable of the Python exception.

```
void translator(const MyCPPException &x) {
    bp::object exc(x); // wrap the C++ exception

    bp::object exc_t(bp::handle<>(bp::borrowed(exceptionType)));
    exc_t.attr("cause") = exc; // add the wrapped exception to the Python exception

    PyErr_SetString(exceptionType, x.what());
}
```

The wrapped C++ exception can then be accessed from Python like this:

```
try:
    ...
except MyModule.MyCPPExceptionType as e:
    cause = e.cause # wrapped exception can be accessed here
```

but the exception will also be caught by

```
try:
    ...
except Exception:
    ...
```

Comment: Note that `exc_t.attr("cause") = exc;` adds the C++ exception instance as an attribute to the Python exception *class*. So if you caught an exception instance e1 in Python and kept a reference to it a second raise of such a C++ exception would change the cause attribute of e1 to refer to the new C++ exception instance.